# Django download the right file from model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I created a web app that allows users to extract geometrical and other data from a 3D model in ifc format. So the user uploads the 3D model, the app gives him some basic info about the model and lets the user decide which data he wants to download in which format (xlsx or csv)

For the uploaded file I have an upload form from the model. And then when the user decides what he wants to download I retrieve the uploaded file using the objects.latest query.

But that can lead to problems, right? If multiple users are uploading files at the same time it can lead to a mismatch. What would a better practice of solving this problem be?

How do I associate the page visitor withe the file he uploaded?

Comment: First you need to create a new object for each upload and then you can store the object id in the session if your users are not logged in. If they are logged in you can use a foreign key to the user in your object model. Just to give you a direction to think.

Comment: The users are not logged in. I allready create an model object from each upload, but how do I store the object id in the session?

Comment: request.session['my_item'] = 'my_item_value'   see also the django sessions documentation